# Как решить конфликт версий jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Есть плагин который с помощью **shortcode** загружается на страницу и он использует свою версию *jquery* а тема использует свою , в итоге плагин не работает на более новой версии *jquery* , как можно решить эту проблему
не отказываясь при этом от новой версии  *jquery*

сейчас в файле `functions.php` подключение выглядит так

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'test-themes-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', array(), '3.3.1', true );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Подключать последнюю версию вместе с плагином [*jquery-migrate*](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#jquery-migrate-plugin) (это если у вас не совсем древняя версия в шаблоне и она может работать с jQuery 1.12.x)
2. Использовать [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Это легко сделать если у вас скрипты на новой версии *jQuery* лежат в отдельном файле (или количество файлов и инлайн-вставок небольшое). Для этого в конце вашего файла c *jQuery 3* (или во вставке сразу после загрузки jQuery3) нужно написать `jq3 = jQuery.noConflict();` (имя переменной выбираете сами) затем обернуть *все* скрипты (именно поэтому это способ только для небольшого количества, если у вас вставок как в опенкарте - этот способ не годится) и вставки в `(function($) { ... })(jq3));`
3. **Правильный путь** (но не всегда оптимальный): Воспользуйтесь [руководством по обновлению](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0) и перепишите все скрипты на последнюю версию. Звучит это, конечно, дико, но если скрипты к теме писал человек с головой (и не под версию <1.7), там потребуется немного шаблонных замен.